# Importing to wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I have a blogging service and would like my users to be able to export their blog from my site to Wordpress. Can someone guide me in creating OPML/XML format or any other way to allow them to import  I am using Ruby on Rails 2.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Provide action which renders XML using view [ActiveView and Builder](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html).
E.g. you can create `export` action in main controller.
Then add `export.builder` file for that controller in views directory.
Using Builder syntax generate OPML output.